# Copying rows from one table to another without duplicates using eloquent/fluent

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
 $product = Book::select('name', 'id', 'user_id')->where('books.user_id', '=', 1)
        ->whereNotExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(3))
                  ->from('music')
                  ->whereRaw('music.name = books.name');

        })
        ->get();
```

The code above selects 3 rows from the books table for a single user where there are no duplicate names between the books table and the music table. However what I want to do is actually copy those rows into music table.

So I would like to do this

```
$product = Book::select('name', 'id', 'user_id')->where('books.user_id', '=', 1)
```

and copy these rows into music table without duplicate names? Also is there a way of copying all the rows and not having to select the number of rows?

Comment: May I suggest that you overlook your database schema, it seems you are storing redundant data, when you have to copy the same information between two tables. Try to normalize your tables. I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, it's just a general tip.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @henrik, however the reason I've designed my database like this is because there are columns in the music table which I simply do not want to put in any other table. Those columns correspond to the new rows I want to copy into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your $product variable to $products as it's more than one.

Then to save from your query into the musuc table imply iterate through the products:

```
// Get the books you want to copy
//using your query or you can also use (distinct()) to get unique records
// iterate through the books that have a unique name
foreach ($products as $product){
    // save them in your music table using either your model or an insert query
    $song = Music::create(array($product->name ...etc...));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @keithm. I've actually had to iterate through the array as key value pairs, grabbing only the values and assigning a variable to each value and then inserting.